# C# Sort, cannot convert lambda expression to System.Array

Tags: c#, lambda

Based on what I've found on .Sort() this should work

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int[] test = new int[] {6, 2, 1, 4, 9, 3, 7};
        test.Sort((a,b) => a<b);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this error message:

```
error CS1660: Cannot convert `lambda expression' to non-delegate type `System.Array'
```

That's the simplest version I could find to get that error.  In my case, I'm taking a string, giving it a complex ranking value, and comparing that.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [overload of Sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx) that you are after expects a [delegate that takes in two objects of the type contained within the array, and returns an `int`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh(v=vs.110).aspx). You need to change your expression to return an `int`, where you return a negative value for items that come before the other, zero when the items are "equal", and a positive value for items that come after the other.

Also, for arrays the `Sort` method is `static`, so you call it using the class name, not as an instance:

```
Array.Sort(test, (left, right) => left.CompareTo(right));
```

`CompareTo` is a built-in function on types that are `IComparable` (like `int`), and it returns an `int` in the manner I described above, so it is convenient to use for sorting.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a better error message for when you are sorting a System.Array.  Thanks so much!

Comment: I'd also like to add, you don't have to use `CompareTo`.  Rolling your own works just as well.